# How to include a compositional independent variable in a discrete choice analysis

Tags: predictor, compositional-data

I am analyzing resource selection in a wildlife species using discrete choice analysis. I have 'used' points (i.e. roosting/den sites) and paired random, available but unused points for comparison. We are comparing use/non-use at three spatial scales around the focal point (buffered circles in ArcGIS) and looking at several quantitative metrics describing each circle. This is a preliminary analysis and thus we don't want to wade into Fragstats or similar territory for detailed metrics of the habitat (e.g. fragmentation, amount of edge, etc). At this point we simply want a way to capture the heterogeneity of canopy heights (from a canopy height model) inside each buffered circle. The canopy height model is stratified into 4 vertical bins representing essentially ground level, subcanopy, mid-upper canopy, and high canopy. The model gives us proportions of each strata in each circle.

Does anyone know of an appropriate or preferred method for entering these data as independent variables in the discrete choice models? We feel that it may not be just the amount of really big, old trees, but the combination of big, old trees and some other component of the heterogeneity.

Thanks for your thoughts. Just trying to come up with a clean way to enter such a compositional component into the choice models. 
I am new to this type of analysis and looking for suggestions or pointers to examples in the literature.